# Kafka avrò can't locate subject

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am producing a Kafka record, using an Avro schema that is registered in Schema Registry.

The subject is registered, because when I hit http://localhost:8081/subjects/player-value/versions/2

I get:

```
{
subject: "player-value",
version: 2,
id: 21,
schema: "{"type":"record","name":"player_value","namespace":"com.mycorp.mynamespace","doc":"Sample schema to help you get started.","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int","doc":"The int type is a 32-bit signed integer."},{"name":"first_name","type":"string","doc":"The string is a unicode character sequence."}]}"
}
```

I am downloading the schema, and then use GenericRecord to produce to a topic with that schema.

I have set the subject value strategy to RecordNamingStragegy.

I create a GenericRecord like this:

```
Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(subject.schema);
                    System.out.println(subject.schema);
                    return new GenericData.Record(schema);
record.put("id", 1);
                    record.put("first_name", "foobar");
```

where subject.schema is:

```
{"type":"record","name":"player_value","namespace":"com.mycorp.mynamespace","doc":"Sample schema to help you get started.","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int","doc":"The int type is a 32-bit signed integer."},{"name":"first_name","type":"string","doc":"The string is a unicode character sequence."}]}
```

However, when I produce, I get this error:

```
SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema: {"type":"record","name":"player_value","namespace":"com.mycorp.mynamespace","doc":"Sample schema to help you get started.","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int","doc":"The int type is a 32-bit signed integer."},{"name":"first_name","type":"string","doc":"The string is a unicode character sequence."}]}
```

This is my full code (which is not needed for you to read all):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        schemaRegistryUtil.downloadSchema("player-value", 2)
                .thenApply(subject -> {
                    Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(subject.schema);
                    System.out.println(subject.schema);
                    return new GenericData.Record(schema);
                })
                .thenApply(record -> {
                    record.put("id", 1);
                    record.put("first_name", "Totti");
                    return record;
                })
                .thenApply(record -> producer.produce("some-key", record, TOPIC))
                .whenCompleteAsync((metadata, throwable) -> {
                    if (throwable != null) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("Error happened %s", throwable.getMessage()));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("all good man");
                    }
                });


    }
```

#### Update

Funny enough, If I remove

```
properties.setProperty(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY, RecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
```

It works well!

Answer (score 0):

There are different naming strategies for the schema subjects in the schema registry.
[This link](https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.0/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html) provides a description of the strategies, the following is an extraction from that page..

> Any implementation of
> `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.SubjectNameStrategy` can be
> specified. By default, `<topic>-value` is used as subject.

The default is `TopicNameStrategy` which comprises of the `topic_name`-*key* or `topic-name`-*value* depending on the configuration [isKey](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serializer.html#configure-java.util.Map-boolean-) supplied to the serializer. This allows the topic to have a single subject.

The other naming strategy is `RecordNameStrategy` that names on the basis of the avro record. From the docs..

> For any Avro record type that is published to Kafka topic `<topicName>`,
> registers the schema in the registry under the subject name
> `<topicName>-<recordName>`, where `<recordName>` is the fully-qualified
> Avro record name.
>
> This strategy allows a topic to contain a mixture of different record
> types, since no intra-topic compatibility checking is performed
>
> Moreover, different topics may contain mutually incompatible versions
> of the same record name, since the compatibility check is scoped to a
> particular record name within a particular topic.

Sometimes, we get exception even if the schema registry is inaccessible, *though* it seems not to be the case for you.